# Securing a Shuffle Algorithm

Tags: cryptography, javascript, random

After reading about writing a secure shuffle algorithm, I realized that my module that generates a password is only as strong as my PRNG, which in this case is `Math.random()`. I'm confused as to how to replace `Math.random()` using SJCL's [PRNG](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.prng.html). What exactly should I be concerned about when generating a secure random value, and more importantly how can I make this more secure (if possible)?

Here's my example:

```
var sjcl = require('sjcl');
var _ = require('underscore');

var shuffle = function (password) {
var size = password.length;
for (var i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  var j = (Math.random() * (i + 1)) | 0;
  var temp = password[i];
  password[i] = password[j];
  password[j] = temp;
}
return password;
};

var generate = function (length) {
  var decimals = _.range(33 + (126 + 1));
  length = length || 10;
  return shuffle(_.map(decimals, function (ascii) {
    return String.fromCharCode(ascii);
  })).join('').slice(0, length);
};
```

Comment: Fyi, the weakness of `Math.random` are known by the TC-39 committee and should be addressed in the next version of the language.  In the meantime, browsers are implementing strong replacements like `window.crypto.getRandomValues`.  [Bug 440046](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=440046) from Mozilla has relevant discussion.

Answer (score 1):

To make a random, *unbiased* shuffle, you apply the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). If you want to shuffle an array *x* of *n* elements (numbered from 0 to *n*-1), you do this:

```
for all i from 0 to n-1
    let j = rnd(n - i) + i
    swap x[i] with x[j]
```

where *rnd(k)* means: generate a random uniform value in the 0 to *k*-1 range. Note that it may happen that *i = j* in the loop above, meaning that you may swap an array element with itself. This is normal, and needed for proper uniform selection of a permutation.

Your problem, then, is how to convert a stream of random *words* into random selections in a smaller range. `sjcl.prng.randomWords()` returns an array of 32-bit words, i.e. values in the 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 range. If you simply divide a word value by *k*, and keep the remainder, then your selection is biased. The trick is to *reject* part of the range, so that the *rnd()* function looks like this:

```
rnd(k):
    while true
        let z = next-random-word
        let r = z mod k
        if z - r + k <= 2^32
            return r
```

For instance, if *k* = 37 (you want a random unbiased integer in the 0 to 36 range), then you generate a random *z*. If that value *z* falls in the 0 to 4294967288 range, then you just reduce the value modulo 37, and you have your random integer; this is unbiased because 4294967289 is a multiple of 37. However, if *z* falls in the 4294967289 to 4294967295 range, you have to try again with another *z*.

(Mathematically speaking, some sort of loop is unavoidable when *k* does not divide 2<sup>32</sup>. The risks of looping many times are negligible, though.)

---

I don't know exactly what you need your shuffle for; if that is for generating a "password" then doing a shuffle of printable characters from 33 to 126 (the ASCII printable characters, excluding space, thus 94 values) is weird, because there is no law against using the same character twice in a password. In fact, forcibly preventing the same character from appearing twice in a password reduces the space of possible passwords, and thereby *reduces* security. To generate a random password, it is simpler and also better to produce each character randomly and independently of the others; fiddling with permutations and shuffling is just unnecessary complexity (and complexity is known to be, in general, harmful to security by itself).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this crypto library https://clipperz.is/open_source/javascript_crypto_library/ which comes with a certified random generator, Fortuna is the name. The Math.random() function is not considered secure for cryptography purposes.

Comment: I've checked that one out before. The main thing I would like an understanding of is how to apply the concepts of generating a secure prng value rather than relying on Math.random(). Most secure prng's rely on either creating a buffer or an array of bytes. I'm shuffle an array of 94 characters. How can I apply this in this case? (I'm not asking for code, but merely an explanation.)